# Adobe Edge HTML5 Local Connection

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, adobe-edge

I`m trying to create two banners with adobeEdge and import them with iframes within 3rd file. So the structure would be something like this:

banner1.html

banner2.html

index.html (where banner1 and banner2 will be embed via iframe).

Those two banners will be animated, however file size, loading time of each may vary so they will not be loaded in the same time.

The problem is that I need them both to start playing in exact same time (in flash that is called local connection), so the idea is to check when both iframes are loaded and if each of them send DONE message to the other one I will play them.

I wrote a code which actually work, but still one banner always has a delay. Here is my code:

**Banner 1**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var fr = window.parent.frames["frame2"];
    var frwin = fr.contentWindow;
    var otherLoaded = false;
    var selfLoaded = false;
    var process = setInterval(function(){load();},10);

    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

    function setLoaded(){
        selfLoaded = true;
        frwin.postMessage("Done", "DOMAIN");
    }

    function load(){
        if(otherLoaded === true && selfLoaded === true){
            clearInterval(process);

            AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function(compId) {
                AdobeEdge.getComposition(compId).getStage().play();
            });

        }else if(selfLoaded === true && otherLoaded !== true){
            frwin.postMessage("resend", "http://izorgor.com");

        }
    }

    function receiveMessage(event) {
        if (event.origin !== "DOMAIN")
            return;

        if(event.data === 'Done'){
            otherLoaded = true;
            console.log("Done");
        }
        if(event.data === 'resend'){
            fr = window.parent.frames["frame2"];
            frwin = fr.contentWindow;
            frwin.postMessage("Done", "DOMAIN");
            console.log("resend");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Banner 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fr = window.parent.frames["frame1"];
    var frwin = fr.contentWindow;
    var otherLoaded = false;
    var selfLoaded = false;
    var process = setInterval(function(){load();},10);

    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

    function setLoaded(){
        selfLoaded = true;
        frwin.postMessage("Done", "DOMAIN");
    }

    function load(){
        if(otherLoaded === true && selfLoaded === true){
            clearInterval(process);

            AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function(compId) {
                AdobeEdge.getComposition(compId).getStage().play();
            });
        }else if(selfLoaded === true && otherLoaded !== true){
            frwin.postMessage("resend", "http://izorgor.com");

        }
    }

    function receiveMessage(event) {
        if (event.origin !== "DOMAIN")
            return;

        if(event.data === 'Done'){
            otherLoaded = true;
            console.log("Done");
        }
        if(event.data === 'resend'){
            fr = window.parent.frames["frame1"];
            frwin = fr.contentWindow;
            frwin.postMessage("Done", "DOMAIN");
            console.log("resend");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**index.html**

```
<iframe width="900" height="200" id="frame1" src="banner1.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should contact your AdServer and ask if they are serving the Ad in just one TAG or in two TAGs

You can use libraries as https://github.com/jeremyharris/LocalConnection.js/tree/master
(similar to Flash Local Connection)

Comment: AdServer is serving wallpaper banner as two different iframes. My first idea was to exchange postMessage between those two (my script above). But for some reason when I have transition of some object between those two formats, I see that hey doesn`t start in exact same time. 

Thanks for this script I will give it a try

Answer (score -1):

You can simply communicate between all your iframes in a window with a JavaScript library that I developed.
 Get [Documentation](http://www.emresakarya.de/local-connection/) or [Fork on GitHub](https://github.com/softberry/Local-Connection). It uses nativ DOM to connect iframes with each other.

Sample usage :
include first LocalConnection script to all your banner. In this sample code we assume there are 2 banners need to communicate with each other. But it works also any number of banners.

in first banner :

```
<script>
        LC.key = 'uniqueConnectionString';
         LC.name = 'right';  // desc: my name is right and
        LC.frames = 'left'; // I want to connect to the banner called left
        LC.onConnect = function () {
            console.log('Do this as soon as connection established!');
            /*
             From this point window of left and top will be available as
             LC.left and LC.top
             for example :
             */
            LC.left.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
        };

    </script>
```

On the second banner put the same code but change name and frames values like this :

```
<script>
        LC.key = 'uniqueConnectionString'; 
        LC.name = 'left';  // desc: my name is left and
        LC.frames = 'right'; // I want to connect to the banner called right
        LC.onConnect = function () {
            console.log('Do this as soon as connection established!');
            /*
             From this point window of left and top will be available as
             LC.left and LC.top
             for example :
             */
            LC.left.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
        };
        LC.connect();
    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).